# What does the green bowtie ribbon represent?

Tags: for-honor

Couldn't find anything about this icon next to someones name online. What does it represent?

[image: green bowtie]

Comment: Hopefully someone who play knows because you won't find that answer online easily... too much comes up about honor medals and league of legends ribbons

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to a [forum](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/1571760-Green-badge?s=bfb3ff1b46f56a67662b4bd8beda3c77&highlight=green+ribbon) on Ubisoft's website:

> the green badge is champion status you can buy it ingame with ingame currency (steel) it costs 2000 steel which gives you 3 days of champion status

Apparently, the green ribbon denotes Champion Status which you can buy with ingame money.  From this [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/forhonor/comments/5n9b42/champion_status/), Champion Status does:

> Champion status is like a "premium" subscription you have. you get more xp and steel and you give a small bonus to your current team as well. each teammember with champion status adds more bonus to everyone else.

Comment: What does champion status do?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer see edit.

Comment: Nice find... Although I would have to say it sounds less like a "premium subscription" and more like a booster similar to the renown boost in rainbow six siege or pretty much any in-game currency/xp booster